# end() iterator of a different type

Tags: c++, c++20

What if a container's `end()` returns an iterator of a different type than `begin()`? Does it violate some principles the iterators are based on?

Sample code that I found in [cppcoro](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro/blob/master/include/cppcoro/generator.hpp) library:

```
namespace detail
{
    struct generator_sentinel {};

    template<typename T>
    class generator_iterator
    {
        //normal iterator implementation with `operator++` and `operator==` goes here.

        friend bool operator==(const generator_iterator& it, generator_sentinel) noexcept
        {
            return !it.m_coroutine || it.m_coroutine.done();
        }

        friend bool operator!=(const generator_iterator& it, generator_sentinel s) noexcept
        {
            return !(it == s);
        }

        friend bool operator==(generator_sentinel s, const generator_iterator& it) noexcept
        {
            return (it == s);
        }

        friend bool operator!=(generator_sentinel s, const generator_iterator& it) noexcept
        {
            return it != s;
        }

        ...
    };
}

template<typename T>
class [[nodiscard]] generator
{
public:

    using promise_type = detail::generator_promise<T>;
    using iterator = detail::generator_iterator<T>;

    ...

    iterator begin()
    {
        if (m_coroutine)
        {
            m_coroutine.resume();
            if (m_coroutine.done())
            {
                m_coroutine.promise().rethrow_if_exception();
            }
        }

        return iterator{ m_coroutine };
    }

    detail::generator_sentinel end() noexcept
    {
        return detail::generator_sentinel{};
    }
};
```

Comment: It just means the library is geared toward `std::ranges::` algorithms instead of the traditional ones.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes the most lib sources were not updated for last 4-5 years.

Comment: And? Ranges were a shoe-in for C++20. As were coroutines.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica it is not coroutines, but `<experimental/coroutine>`

Comment: It definetly violates the [`Container` named requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container).

Comment: @fabian - Good, it's not a container

Comment: @Dmitriano - you are splitting hairs, again

Comment: @fabian @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica so, `generator` is not a container and we can't use `ranges` with its `begin()`, `end()`, but we but what prevents us from using range-based loop?

Comment: Why can't we use ranges? Ranges do support this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, `static_assert(std::ranges::range<generator<int>>);` does not fail.